# UIPicker and Text Field

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmutablearray, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have the same kind of question as this person
[How to Sync selected row of UIPicker with previously entered data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917186/how-to-sync-selected-row-of-uipicker-with-previously-entered-data)

I want the picker to load with info from a text field in another tab. I'll explain.

I have a doctor tab where the user fills in all the info about their doctor or add from contacts. In another tab where they need to reference a doctor, instead of asking them to type in the same info I figure just use a picker.

But I would like to know if creating a NSMutableArray in the init, using -viewDidLoad: and then of course dealloc is just as sufficient as iterating. And should I have a separate class for the picker and just reference it?

Hope my question makes sense. Thanks in advance!

I apologize, I forgot to add I'm using Core Data if that makes a difference at all. But thanks to iamsult and the69geeks for the answers, I'll considering both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create object for class A say doctorTab in class B (reference tab). Now access the array of class A through object doctorTab from class B.

```
NSMutableArray *referencedDoc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
referencedDoc = doctorTab.doctorArray;
```

doctorArray is the array defined in class A.

Hope this would work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I forgot to add I'm using Core Data if that makes a difference to your answer. I'm sorry. I should have added that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest best way is to keep a `shared NSMutableArray` in AppDelegate, fill it from the `UITextField` and use it in `UIPicker`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I forgot to add I'm using Core Data if that makes a difference to your answer. I'm sorry. I should have added that.